# Why asset not loading well in webview?

Tags: webview, android-jetpack-compose

Trying to debug a jetpack compose app which uses webview inside horizontal pager i get the below icon. When i try to load second page there are loading at the same time 2 instances. I noticed that as soon as there is next page the problem exists. When i reach last page everything works as expected. Any one had ever the same problem?

[image]